# Accessing a inherited function from child

Tags: javascript, inheritance

The first code:

```js
function Animal() {}
Animal.prototype.eat = function() {
  console.log("nom nom nom");
};

function Dog() {}
Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Dog.prototype = {
  constructor: Dog,
  bark: function() {
    console.log("Woof!");
  }
};
let beagle = new Dog();
console.clear();
beagle.eat(); // Should print "nom nom nom" but displays a error that eat 
//is not a function.
beagle.bark();
```

The second code:

```js
function Animal() {}
Animal.prototype.eat = function() {
  console.log("nom nom nom");
};

function Dog() {}
Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;
Dog.prototype.bark = function() {
  console.log("Woof!");
}
let beagle = new Dog();
console.clear();
beagle.eat(); // Prints "nom nom nom"
beagle.bark(); // Prints "Woof!"
```

What is the wrong with the first code snippet that `beagle.eat()` doesn't shows the correct output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're first assigning `Dog`'s prototype as `Object.create(Animal.prototype);`, but then on the next line you *completely reassign* `Dog`'s prototype to something else, so the inheritance chain no longer exists. Tweaking your first code, you might want to just assign to `Dog.prototype` only once and use `Object.assign` along with `Object.create`:

```js
function Animal() {}
Animal.prototype.eat = function() {
  console.log("nom nom nom");
};

function Dog() {}
Dog.prototype = Object.assign(
  Object.create(Animal.prototype),
  {
    constructor: Dog,
    bark: function() {
      console.log("Woof!");
    }
  }
);
let beagle = new Dog();
beagle.eat();
```

Comment: Thanks, dude. I've one question if I expand the `Animal.prototype` inside the `Dog.prototype` using spread operator. Will it work? Like a alternative to inherit the parent's function using `Object.create()`.

Comment: To a limited extent, yes, you could use spread: `Dog.prototype = { ...Animial.prototype, constructor: Dog, bark: ... }` But there wouldn't be any inheritence there, you'd simply be copying the references to `Animal`'s prototype's functions, but the `Dog` wouldn't actually be linked to the `Animal` otherwise. For example, if you added a function to `Animal`'s prototype *after* assigning `Dog`'s prototype, if you used spread rather than `Object.create`, any `Dog` would not be access the new function on `Animal`. So, better to use `Object.create`